# Optimising MySQL update for lots of rows

Tags: mysql

Say I have a table with columns A, B, C, D, E and F. A, B and C are the primary keys in this table.

I grab a set of rows like:

```
SELECT A, B, C, D FROM table WHERE C > 10;
```

Now I want to update each E (and I use the value of D to do this) for every row in that result set. What is the best way of doing this?

- Just run a `UPDATE table SET E=value WHERE .....` query for each entry?
- Do one `REPLACE INTO table VALUES ...` query (but as this does a delete if a row exist I need to also read F in the earlier SELECT)
- ??

I have potentially a fair amount of rows (several hundreds of thousands). Is it perhaps better to do this in 'blocks' at a time? (not that I run out of RAM/swapspace any-time soon)

Comment: ?? Forget about the SELECT. Just run one UPDATE query.

Comment: It wasn't clear from my question, but I need the value of D to update E, I have to do the SELECT.

Comment: No. You do not need the select. If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: There is no 'problem' as such. I can't provide the DDL as it contains sensitive info which is why I asked the question as I did. I basically need to update column E using the value from column D for each row that matches the WHERE clause on C (which is a primary key). I was just after the 'best' way of doing this. I currently simply do the select, perform all my calculations and then update each row.

Answer (score 0):

If all E's in the set will get the same value, it's easy:

`UPDATE table SET 'E' = "value" WHERE 'C' > 10;`

If not, and the E's get different values due to external logic, you need to stay with iterating over the set and updating row by row.

This can be optimized. Try to open an updatable cursor on the result set and issue the update directly from there or generate a batch based on a prepared statement.

Comment: E's are different and depend on the value of D (which is why I have to do the select in the first place)